# stat_contour() to fill areas from bathymetry marmap

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

According with @missuse answer to this question
[Plot bathymetry and coastline using ggplot2 and marmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119592/plot-bathymetry-and-coastline-using-ggplot2-and-marmap)

I generated this plot 
[image]

By this script

```
Bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 37, lon2 = 38.7,
                       lat1 = -45.5, lat2 = -47.3, resolution = 1)
Bathy <- as.matrix(Bathy)
class(Bathy) <- "matrix"

Bathydf <- as.data.frame(Bathy)
Bathydf <- rownames_to_column(Bathydf, var = "Longitude")
Bathydf <- gather(Bathydf,Latitude,Depth, -1)
Bathydf <- mutate_all(.tbl = Bathydf, funs(as.numeric))


ggplot(data = ctd, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Chla)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(my_colours)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = Chla), binwidth = 2, colour = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = Chla), breaks = 0.1, colour = "darkgrey") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = Chla), breaks = 0.2, colour = "darkgrey") +
  geom_contour(aes(z = Chla), breaks = 0.3, colour = "black") +

  geom_contour(data = subset(Bathydf, Depth < 0),aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, z = Depth),
               bins = 10, colour = "darkgray") +
  stat_contour(data = subset(Bathydf, Depth >= 0),geom="polygon",
               aes(z = Depth), fill = "black") +

  geom_contour(data = Bathydf, aes(z = Depth), breaks = 1000, colour = "black", alpha = 1) + 
  geom_point(data = ctd, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),
             colour = 'black', size = 3, alpha = 1, shape = 15) +


  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

It works, but I am not sure if using `stat_contour()` is the best way to plot the areas. Furthermore, plotting the areas of the islands, it colours also some parts of them, making the shape wired.
Do you think to use `stat_contour()` is the best way to plot the areas, and do you know why it plots also the wired spots around the big black area?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [my solution in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119592/plot-bathymetry-and-coastline-using-ggplot2-and-marmap)?

Have you checked the help file for `marmap::autoplot.bathy`? Have you looked at the examples there, and especially the `geom="contour"` argument? Is it not doing what you want to achieve?